# 'PORT' is not recognized as an internal or external command React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Someone shared with me the code of an application, now I am trying to study it, understand the code before moving on to the next stage of improving it. Funny that the developer is  missing in action and he didn't  document anything.

Now, launching the app only has been a problem and I notice the error is coming  from **package.json** file. This is the section with the code error:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=3333 bash -c 'node scripts/start.js'",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
  },
```

Now I am running this app on *VS CODE* on *windows 10*. I understand on windows you don't have to declare the **port** at all on that *start line* but I am wondering how can I rewrite the *start line* so that to have it working. Any ideas will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Changing start to just `node scripts/start.js` should work.

Comment: `"start": "SET PORT=3333 && node scripts/start.js"` Please try this, it should work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Linux shell command

```bash
PORT=3333 bash -c 'node scripts/start.js'
```

starts a new `bash` process with the environment variable `PORT` set to `3333`, cf. e.g. [How do I set an environment variable on the command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/56444).

For cross-pltform compatibility, you can use the [`cross-env` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env). (Note however that it's only in maintainance mode.) You can probably use this:

```bash
cross-env PORT=3333 node scripts/start.js
```